# Problemas en el buscar algunas palabras en base de datos

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un tabla cursos que tiene 3067 registros, cree un buscador para poder filtrar por cursos mi problema se basa cuando la coloco palabra "anat" me salen todas las opciones(anatomia, anatomia humana, anatomia clinica, ect), pero cuando coloco calculo, algebra o gestion(tambien puse cal, calc, alg , ges) no me sale ningún curso para seleccionar la verdad ya he probado varias opciones pero ninguna me da soluciones, quizás tenga problemas en la consulta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Autocomplete</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <label>Search Cursos</label>
   <input type="text" name="cursos" id="cursos" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del curso" />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#cursos').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

```html
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "encuesta1");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["nombre"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto el código si alguien me pueda ayudar o orientar seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: cálculo, álgebra o gestión tienen tilde, ya probaste buscando con las tildes? Revisa como están guardados en tu DB, aunque anatomía también tiene tilde el problema puede ser como están guardados

Comment: Hola, están sin tilde y todas con mayúsculas ingresadas en la BD.

Comment: Yo haría lo siguiente: **1.** Establecería el charset a la conexión: `$connect->set_charset("utf8");` **2.** No usaría `mysqli_real_escape_string`... no te ayuda a *escapar* de nada. Por el contrario, aplicaría consultas preparadas... pero ese es otro tema. **3.** Revisaría si la columna `nombre` no es *caseinsensitive* Eso lo puedes verificar en PHPMyAdmin, en la pestaña `estructura`. Si la columna dice algo como esto `utf8_spanish_ci` debajo de `Cotejamiento`... el `ci` final significa que es *caseinsensitive*, o sea, que no distingue entre mayúsculas  o minúsculas acentuadas o no.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero ya lo solucione como eran muchos registros cambie la consulta  $query = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$request."%' y puse esto $query = "
 SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre LIKE '".$request."%' LIMIT 5
"; 
";

Answer (score 0):

Después de la sentencia

```
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
```

Pon lo siguiente:

```
$request = htmlspecialchars($request);
```

Comment: Hola, aplique lo que me dijiste pero aun sigue igual pero ahora descubrí que si coloco calculo num me sale calculo numerico para elegir, pero aun no entiendo si pongo calculo porq no me salen todas las opciones posibles

Comment: ya solucione mi problema era cambiar esto 
$query = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$request."%'"; y coloque esto $query = "
 SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre LIKE '".$request."%' LIMIT 5
"; como eran muchos datos no me salen todos los registros